# Using IF controller

Tags: jmeter, code-duplication, jsr223

I want to check a condition before each HTTP request.

I have an access token and a refresh token.

Once the access token is expired, the refresh token end point is called to generate a new access token.(oauth2).

So after every HTTP request, I want check whether the access token is expired. That can be achieved, if I add a jmeter IF controller after each HTTP request. Is there a way to set the IF controller globally(without checking before each request).

I check the expiry time using JSR223 post processor and depending on the result, I execute the IF controller. I want to set this IF controller globally to avoid duplication.

JSR 223 Post processor

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
long expiryTime = sdf.parse(vars.get("expiry_time")).getTime();
long currentTime = sdf.parse(vars.get("time")).getTime();
long timeleft = currentTime - expiryTime;
vars.putObject("isExpired",timeleft);
```

IF controller condition before each HTTP request

```
${__jexl3(${isExpired}>0,)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) and put your If Controller and JSR223 inside [Test fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) for reuse

> Module Controller provides a mechanism for substituting test plan fragments into the current test plan at run-time.
>
> A test plan fragment consists of a Controller and all the test elements (samplers etc.) contained in it. The fragment can be located in any Thread Group. If the fragment is located in a Thread Group, then its Controller can be disabled to prevent the fragment being run except by the Module Controller. Or you can store the fragments in a dummy Thread Group, and disable the entire Thread Group.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I use test fragment to store JSR223 and IF controller, how can I call them after each HTTP requests, I have around 20 requests.

Comment: I suppose, I have to add a module controller before each HTTP request right? So , if I have 20 requests, I need to add 20 module controllers. Is it a good practice to use so?

Comment: @user3153582 yes, it just points to test fragement ,similar to call a method

Comment: Thank you so much :) Really appreciate your help.